# How to render html content in blog postings - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a blog.

So far i have made a namespace called blog and have posts as nested routes

```
namespace :blog do
  get '', to: 'welcome#index', as: '/'
  resources :posts
end
```

My question is how do I create and save HTML in database and render it when the user wants to view a particular post?

In other words how do I create, save and render structured content?

Comment: I'd say markdown but I can't remember if it does allow you to use html in line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save HTML in a TEXT column in your database.

You are probably concerned about safety of this HTML.

There are several options to consider.

**A**. If you can afford it, better to go with Markdown (like SO). You can then use [kramdown](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) gem to transform Markdown into HTML.

**B**. If you can't use markdown in your project, then before displaying saved HTML to user, use [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize) helper:

```
<%= sanitize @post.html %>
```

You also ask about creation of HTML. You should probably use any editor which convert your `<textarea>` tag into an advanced HTML editor. One possibility is to use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which also has [specialized gem](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) for Rails.